# Make a slideshow in iPhoto 9.6.1 showing photos in random order

Tags: photos.app, slideshow

I want to make a slideshow that shows photos in random order, but I don't see the option to do it. I only have an option to sort images by name or date or things that do not apply.

Answer (score 1):

There is no ***preset*** for random order – but you can switch to random order ("shuffle order") while the slideshow is actually playing:

> "*While a slideshow is playing, move the pointer to make the slideshow controls appear, and then click the Settings button*"

The settings button is the little *cog wheel icon* next to the close [X] button:

[image]

Clicking the settings button in play mode will open an extended preferences panel, featuring an additional option "*Shuffle slide order*" in the lower third of the panel:

[image]

Checking/unchecking that option will toggle the Shuffle mode.

You can find a detailled description on this page ["Change slideshow settings"](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH15201?locale=en_US)at support.apple.com – it's for iPhoto 9.5 but should also apply for iPhoto 9.6.

Comment: The shuffle slide order box isn't clickable. You can see that it is a slightly darker tint above.

Comment: I think the screenshot was made from an image folder I just created for that screenshot, containing only 1 image –– I suppose the slideshow option was 'inactive' because there was only one image in that folder. I now took another screenshot from a multi-image settings panel and updated the screenshot.

Comment: This is no longer possible in Photos, the iPhoto replacement. Any ideas?